# php str_replace unexpected char replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to change some words to numbers. Example is below-

```
$status= str_replace(array("canceled","shipped","processing","complete","pending_payment","closed","fraud","holded","payment_review","pending"),array(4,6,2,10,1,12,0,1,1,2),$sale["status"]);
```

But if unexpected words come from DB ı want to change it to 0.

Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Use a simple switch statement, much easier to read and maintain and offers a `default` directive.

Comment: Actually i used it if conditions something like this;elseif status1="pending" then
status=2
else
status=0
end if

But I dont know how i can do this with str_replace

Comment: Maybe `if (!in_array($sale["status"], array(4,6,2,10,1,12,0,1,1,2)) { $sale["status"] = 0 } else { str_replace stuff}`? ... or you could just ternary the assignment... or you could do this in DB with a `case` and `in`.

Comment: use `preg_replace()` :-https://eval.in/741019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
   $statuses = [
      "canceled" => 4,
      "shipped" => 6,
      "processing" => 2,
      "complete" => 10, 
      "pending_payment" => 1,
      "closed" => 12,
      "fraud" => 0,
      "holded" => 1,
      "payment_review" => 1,
      "pending" => 2,
    ];

    $status = 0;

    if (isset($statuses[$sale["status"]])) { 
        $status = $statuses[$sale["status"]];
    }
```

This way you can easily see which string value maps to which number. Set the default for $status variable to 0. If the status string given, exists in your "statusmap", replace the $status variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$status_words = array("canceled", "shipped", "processing", "complete", "pending_payment", "closed", "fraud", "holded", "payment_review", "pending");
$status_ints = array(4, 6, 2, 10, 1, 12, 0, 1, 1, 2);
$status = (in_array(trim($sale["status"]), $status_words) ? 
           str_replace($status_words, $status_ints, trim($sale["status"])) : '');
```

Give it a try, this should work.